# Tail bound on dependent sum

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

Let R be a random variable, and let X_i be a nonlinear, nonconvex function that takes R and outputs a value in [-1,1].

I'm trying to get a tail bound on the following dependent sum:

$P_R[\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i(R) - E_R[X_i(R)])^2 > \epsilon]<?$

I could use Hoeffding bounds on the terms in the sum as 
$Pr_R[(X_i(R) - E_R[X_i(R)])^2 > t^2] \le 2\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})$ and then union bound, which would give:

$\epsilon = N t^2$ with probability $2N\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})$

My question is: Is there any way to avoid the union bound and get rid of the N factor in front of $\exp$?

Comment: What does that sum represent? The notation suggests it is intended to be a probability, but the argument is not an event. Did you perhaps forget to type part of an inequality?